# Best way to minify all resulted js

Tags: angular

I'm building Angular2 app. I wonder what is the **best** way to **minify** all resulted js files for the app and **concat** it into 1 single file?

**Gulp file:**

```
var paths = {
concatJsSrc : [
           "node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js",
           "node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.min.js",
           "node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js",
           "node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.min.js",
           "node_modules/@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.min.js",
           "node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.min.js",
           "node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.min.js",
           "node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.min.js",
           "node_modules/@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.min.js",
           "node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.min.js",
           "node_modules/@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.min.js",
           "node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js",
           "node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js",
           "node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js",
           "Scripts/systemjs.config.js",
           "Scripts/app/**/*.js",
           "Scripts/theme.js"
       ],
   concatJsDest: "application.min.js"
};
gulp.task("min:js", 
function() {
   return gulp.src(paths.concatJsSrc)
       .pipe(concat(paths.concatJsDest))
       .pipe(uglify())
       .pipe(gulp.dest("/app")); });
```

**Index.html file:**

```
<script src="app/application.min.js"></script>
<script>
   System.import('app')
       .catch(function (err) {
           console.error(err);
       });
</script>
```

**systejs.config.js file:**

```
(function (global) {
   System.config({
   paths: {
       'npm:': "libs/"
   },
   map: {
       app: "app",
       '@angular/core': "npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.min.js",
       '@angular/common': "npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.min.js",
       '@angular/compiler': "npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.min.js",
       '@angular/platform-browser': "npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.min.js",
       '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': "npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.min.js",
       '@angular/http': "npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.min.js",
       '@angular/router': "npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.min.js",
       '@angular/forms': "npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.min.js",
       '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap': "npm:@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js",
       'rxjs': "npm:rxjs",
       'angular-in-memory-web-api': "npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js"
   },
   packages: {
       app: {
           main: "./application.min.js",
           //main: "./main.js",
           defaultExtension: "js"
       },
       rxjs: {
           defaultExtension: "js"
       }
   }
   });})(this);
```

Comment: Check `GRUNT` or `GULP`

Comment: I use GULP to do that. However have error "System is not defined" when app runs.

Comment: Then provide the gulp code used to minify/concat and show us the error. Then we can help you

Comment: Just added content of that files

Comment: Just use webpack. It will save you a lot of pain. Or angular-cli(https://github.com/angular/angular-cli), which internally uses webpack.

Answer (score 1):

We can use GULP to do the concat, minify, uglify and vesioning process of JS files. We have created a **'scripts-minify-concat-versioning'** gulp task which concats JS files (**file1.js, file2.js and file3.js**), minify, uglify and version the file. The result file will be **app.min.js** and will be found at location **build/src/js**.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var rev = require('gulp-rev');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

var scriptFiles = [
   "file1.js", "file2.js", "file3.js"
];

gulp.task('scripts-minify-concat-versioning', [], function () {
    return gulp.src(scriptFiles)
        .pipe(concat("app.min.js"))                                  // Make a single file
        .pipe(uglify())                                              // Make the file titchy tiny small
        .pipe(rev())                                                 // Suffix a version number to it
        .pipe(gulp.dest("build/src/js"));
});
```